# How to sum up properties' values from datamember in C#?

Tags: c#, datamember

I have an event class defined as the following:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class BaseEvent
{
    [DataMember]
    public int count { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SubEventClass SubEventClass { get; set; }
}
```

and a `SubEventClass` defined as the following:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class SubEventClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Width { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public long Length { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public long Area { get; set; }
}
```

I expected to merge/sum two `BaseEvent` objects values by calling this method:

```
public static BaseEvent MergeQueryShapeStats(BaseEvent obj1, BaseEvent obj2)
{
    obj1.count += obj2.count;

    var properties = typeof(SubEventClass).GetProperties();

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(obj2.SubEventClass, null);

        if (value != null)
            prop.SetValue(obj1.SubEventClass, value, null);
    }

    return obj1;
}
```

This following code, to my knowlege, just sets values from obj2 to obj1:

```
prop.SetValue(obj1.SubEventClass, value, null);
```

Does anybody know how to sum values of obj2 and reset obj1?

Thanks

Comment: `v1 = GetValue(obj1); v2=GetValue(obj2); SetValue(obj1, v1+v2);`?

Comment: Why are you overkill getting the type of the properties of SubEventClass if you already know the object at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Oh. It's resolved by the following change:

1. change the prop type to long in SubEventClass
2. call this method:

```
       public static BaseEvent MergeQueryShapeStats(BaseEvent obj1, BaseEvent obj2)
        {
            obj1.count += obj2.count;

            var properties = typeof(SubEventClass).GetProperties();

            foreach (var prop in properties)
            {
                var value2 = prop.GetValue(obj2.SubEventClass, null);

                if (value2 != null)
                {
                    var value1 = prop.GetValue(obj1.SubEventClass, null);
                    prop.SetValue(obj1.SubEventClass, long.Parse(value1.ToString()) + long.Parse(value2.ToString()), null);
                }
            }

            return obj1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to get the types of the properties if you already know the object.

**If there is no solution in your method to resolve the null value, you should check the null before pass the obj1 and obj2**

```
 public static BaseEvent MergeQueryShapeStats(BaseEvent obj1, BaseEvent obj2)
    {
        return new BaseEvent() {
            count = obj1.count + obj2.count,
            SubEventClass  = new SubEventClass() {
                Width = obj1.SubEventClass.Width  + obj2.SubEventClass.Width,
                Length = obj1.SubEventClass.Length + obj2.SubEventClass.Length ,
                Area = obj1.SubEventClass.Area + obj2.SubEventClass.Area   

            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, for these 3 props, it's not needed to use GetProperties(). I need it because I need to merge two objects with more than 10 props defined. This piece of code is an example.

Comment: @Deritha if the object is not dynamic, you should still make the mapping.